# Change on Visual basic 6 application, exe crashes

Tags: crash, vb6

For my customer i had to do a change in a visual basic 6 application running on a windows xp computer.

It's nothing special, just communicating with a plc and functions as a user interface.

My changes work absolute perfect in developer environment(IDE), but when i create the exe it crashes when opening some forms or pressing some buttons. Some stuff works, and some stuff crashes.

Compiler in develop doesn't give any errors even after full compile!

I found some "bugs" by iterating the code and this really is just deleting some variables. (that already existed + **It isn't a programmable error**) The compiler doesn't give an error, just the exe crashes on it.

An example from bug that crashed:

```
sub On form_load()

   Some code

Global_String_Variabel = "Something"

   some code

End sub
```

By deleting the global string variable just in this form, it didn't crash any more.

It's weird because this peace of code already existed, works perfectly fine in develop but not in .exe

Does somebody have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message you get and the corresponding code.

Comment: I don't get an error message, just blank screen.

Comment: The fact that a program which correctly compiles crashes at runtime is, in itself, not surprising at all. The compiler cannot anticipate everything which may happen at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the program runs on your development machine both in IDE and compiled in both states, with the string assign and without, yet works only without on the client's machine.  Something like this happened to me many years ago, and while it may not be your problem, you might at least be able to rule it out.  The client may have a virus scanner that erroneously thinks that a segment of your code is malware.  Just adding another line like x = x or something else benign can sometimes fix it.

You may also need to look further into other differences, like other things they have/run that you don't.

Not that it should matter but are you declaring the variable somewhere and using Option Explicit?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I checked it with my customer, and there wasn't a firewall running and virusscanner since evrything runs local and not/never connected to the internet. 
When i started with the project i added option explicit.